# Accessing a memory mapped file using multiple processes slows down code

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, cython

I have a program running on Windows that uses Python's multiprocessing module to chunk a calculation into `n_core` blocks and then uses `map_async` to run each block on a separate processor. I noticed that I'm not scaling linearly with the number of cores. Several of the computationally heavy method calls, I wrap in a little timing function that only takes into account the calculation and not the setup and teardown and noticed that they were actually taking longer in the parallel runs. In other words, while the overall wallclock time was decreasing with the number of cores, the cpu time (which should be fairly constant) was increasing. These timers are called in the same way for both the serial code path and the parallel code path.

One such method, which took a total of 10 seconds in serial, but close to 20 seconds in aggregate when broken up and run on 4 cores, reads through a memory mapped file (using the `mmap` module) containing array data and pulls a subset of the data into a module variable c array of pointers in cython. The access into the data is fairly random. If I insert a long `sleep` of random length in the method that `map_async` calls, such that each process completes it chunk with the other processes either sleeping or completed, I recover the 10 second total timing. Strangely, if I launch 4 serial runs in quick succession, I see a small slowdown in the time it takes to run this method in each, but it's not nearly as bad as when I go through the multiprocessing code (maybe 12-13 seconds).

This would seem to suggest that there is some sort of collision between the processes as they attempt to read the memmapped file. Should this be a bottleneck? Could this be a Windows issue (I don't do much development on this platform)? I'm only sending and returning data from each process one time in each direction, so this isn't your typical issue of communication/pickling overhead.

Suggestions for what might be going on here, or how to get to the bottom of this would be appreciated. Running `cProfile` within each process didn't suggest anything obvious. Unfortunately the code is complicated enough that I can't post a self contained example here.

**Update**: I see the same behavior on OSX, so it isn't a platform specific issue

**Update #2**: If I run 4 serial jobs in quick succession, but each only performs its calculation on 1 chunk of data, then I see the same ~2x slowdown outside of the context of multiprocessing. Strangely, as I mentioned before, if I launch 4 serial jobs that process the complete dataset, then there is only a 10-20% slowdown in each. So this isn't a multiprocessing issue. Title changed to reflect this.

Comment: Can you try posting the code? or at least a simplified version of it, or what your code does/simulates? Did you consider pycuda instead of multiprocessing on cpu?